# Is there any way to append data to a .xml file in unix?

Tags: xml, unix, sed, append

I have a XML file with below data:

```
<Loggers>
<Root level="WARN">
        <AppenderRef ref="rolling" />
</Root>

<Logger name="com.windows.indexing.EntityQqlQuery" level="info"/>
<Logger name="com.windows.portal.module.questionnaire.object.campaign.helper.CampaignHelper" level="info"/>
<Logger name="com.windows.portal.application.module.searching.DetectionInnerHitSearchQuery" level="info"/>
<Logger name="com.windows.portal.application.module.business.processor.DynamicProcessor" level="ERROR"/>
<Logger name="com.windows.platform.persistence.hibernate.mapping.BasicResultTransformer" level="ERROR"/>
</Loggers>
```

I want to add the below line before `</Loggers>` in the file:

```
<Logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="debug"/>
```

Also the file should be saved after inserting this line. Is there any way that I can achieve it ?

Comment: That can be done with any xslt processor and a suitable stylesheet. [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) is another alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest (probably not best) solution

```
sed -i .bak '/<\/Loggers>/ i \
<Logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="debug"/>\
' filename
```

This will insert a line before each occurence of  line.